# JSON map too big -- how to find the right scale and projection?

Tags: javascript, json, geojson

I am trying to adapt [Mike Bostock's map tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) for a different map. I have this working code using the uk.json file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

/* CSS goes here. */

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

/* JavaScript goes here. */


var width=960, height=1160;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height) ; 


d3.json("./shapefiles/uk.json", function(error, uk){
     if (error) return console.error(error);
     svg.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.feature(uk,uk.objects.subunits))
        .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.mercator()));
});


</script>
```

But when I try to use a similar design with my new.json file all I get is a big black rectangle instead of a map.

This is how the uk.json file starts out:

```
{"type":"Topology","objects":{"subunits":{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"MultiPolygon","properties":{"name":"England"},"id":"ENG","arcs":[[[0]],[[1]],[[2]],[[3]],[[4]],[[5]],[[6,7,8,9]]]},{"type":"MultiPolygon","properties":{"name":"Ireland"},"id":"IRL","arcs":[[[10]],[[11]],[[12]],[[13]],[[14]],[[15]],[[16,17]]]},{"type":"MultiPolygon","properties":{"name":"N. Ireland"},"id":"NIR","arcs":[[[-17,18]],[[19]]]},{"type":"MultiPolygon","properties":{"name":"Scotland"},"id":"SCT","arcs":[[[20]],[[21]],[[22]],[[23]],[[24]],[[25]],[[26]],[[27]],[[28]],[[29]],[[30]],[[31]],[[32]],[[33]],[[34]],[[35]],[[36]],[[37]],[[38]],[[39]],[[40]],[[41]],[[42]],[[43]],[[44]],[[45]],[[46]],[[47]],[[48]],[[-9,49]],[[50]],[[51]],[[52]],[[53]],[[54]],[[55]],[[56]],[[57]],[[58]],[[59]],[[60]],[[61]],[[62]],[[63]],[[64]],[[65]],[[66]]]},{"type":"MultiPolygon","properties":{"name":"Wales"},"id":"WLS","arcs":[[[67]],[[-7,68]],[[69]]]}]},"places":{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Ros Comain"},"coordinates":[3562,3404]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Muineachan"},"coordinates":[4349,3968]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Greenock"},"coordinates":[5782,5506]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Sunderland"},"coordinates":[7961,4580]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Southampton"},"coordinates":[7948,905]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Bristol"},"coordinates":[7183,1408]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Bournemouth"},"coordinates":[7625,750]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Omagh"},"coordinates":[4133,4288]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Chester"},"coordinates":[6965,3008]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Swansea"},"coordinates":[6299,1573]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Carlisle"},"coordinates":[6959,4544]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Southend-on-Sea"},"coordinates":[9319,1500]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Reading"},"coordinates":[8220,1426]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Leicester"},"coordinates":[8121,2487]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Bradford"},"coordinates":[7722,3556]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Sheffield"},"coordinates":[7884,3160]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Shannon"},"coordinates":[3122,2554]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Waterford"},"coordinates":[4255,2147]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Tralee"},"coordinates":[2570,2155]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Donegal"},"coordinates":[3605,4333]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Fort William"},"coordinates":[5548,6314]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Ayr"},"coordinates":[5868,5065]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Aberdeen"},"coordinates":[7509,6637]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Perth"},"coordinates":[6610,5933]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Dundee"},"coordinates":[6914,5997]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Middlesbrough"},"coordinates":[8058,4270]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Coventry"},"coordinates":[7884,2295]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Bath"},"coordinates":[7334,1348]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Exeter"},"coordinates":[6571,723]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Cambridge"},"coordinates":[8929,2094]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Kingston upon Hull"},"coordinates":[8640,3511]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Londonderry"},"coordinates":[4112,4654]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Lisburn"},"coordinates":[4540,4215]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Penzance"},"coordinates":[5265,205]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"York"},"coordinates":[8155,3712]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Blackpool"},"coordinates":[6881,3584]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Dumfries"},"coordinates":[6558,4715]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Scarborough"},"coordinates":[8576,3995]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Plymouth"},"coordinates":[6164,435]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Ipswich"},"coordinates":[9610,1975]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Norwich"},"coordinates":[9694,2487]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Brighton"},"coordinates":[8744,842]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Kirkwall"},"coordinates":[6946,8280]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Inverness"},"coordinates":[6116,6909]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Oxford"},"coordinates":[8045,1701]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Luton"},"coordinates":[8582,1802]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Portsmouth"},"coordinates":[8155,814]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Peterborough"},"coordinates":[8692,2441]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Nottingham"},"coordinates":[8097,2798]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Stoke"},"coordinates":[7444,2825]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Dover"},"coordinates":[9694,1119]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Drogheda"},"coordinates":[4749,3483]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Dundalk"},"coordinates":[4704,3740]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Galway"},"coordinates":[3002,3074]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Kilkenny"},"coordinates":[4164,2509]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Killarney"},"coordinates":[2700,1957]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Sligo"},"coordinates":[3368,3983]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Edinburgh"},"coordinates":[6772,5520]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Newcastle"},"coordinates":[7818,4655]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Liverpool"},"coordinates":[6965,3207]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Cardiff"},"coordinates":[6768,1454]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Wick"},"coordinates":[6860,7792]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Leeds"},"coordinates":[7831,3586]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Cork"},"coordinates":[3360,1818]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Lerwick"},"coordinates":[8110,9361]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Limerick"},"coordinates":[3277,2519]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Manchester"},"coordinates":[7399,3284]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Birmingham"},"coordinates":[7611,2347]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Belfast"},"coordinates":[5000,4288]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Glasgow"},"coordinates":[6104,5454]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"Dublin"},"coordinates":[4811,3131]},{"type":"Point","properties":{"name":"London"},"coordinates":[8777,1456]}]}},"arcs":[[[4788,4],[-7,-4],[-7,4],[1,12],[5,8],[5,-3],[5,-9],[-2,-8]],[[4763,36],[-4,-7],[-6,3],[-4,11],[-1,7],[5,-1],[3,-2],[2,-1],[4,-3],[1,-7]],[[8016,789],[98,-36],[16,1],[6,-1],[8,-6],[1,-2],[-1,-8],[0,-2],[2,-1],[6,1],[1,0],[14,-19],[0,-7],[-3,0],[-2,-2],[-1,-2],[-3,-2],[-24,-7],[-10,-4],[-18,-14],[-4,-5],[-2,-4],[1,-20],[-1,-10],[-2,-5],[-72,-19],[-23,6],[-84,54],[-5,6],[-21,13],[-8,3],[-24,-2],[-11,-4],[-11,-7],[15,26],[26,20],[56,23],[-1,-3],[-2,-6],[-1,-3],[16,2],[15,11],[22,24],[16,10],[15,1]],[[8247,803],[0,-6],[-53,6],[0,7],[14,5],[17,26],[8,0],[6,-5],[2,-6],[-3,-5],[-5,-4],[0,-5],[3,-3],[6,-7],[5,-3]],[[5838,1147],[-5,-4],[-5,6],[-1,13],[3,11],[3,2],[3,-7],[1,-3],[1,-6],[0,-12]],[[9459,1336],[-16,-6],[-75,5],[-13,5],[-11,10],[-10,12],[-6,12],[9,25],[4,5],[9,2],[80,-24],[6,-4],[7,-4],[14,-14],[6,-13],[-4,-11]],[[7130,1561],[-5,19],[0,8],[-3,7],[-4,4],[0,3],[2,2],[10,4],[2,3],[0,3],[-1,5],[-2,5],[-5,16],[-5,12],[-1,5],[0,4],[4,5],[3,4],[2,7],[0,5],[-4,8],[-3,6],[0,7],[1,5],[2,8],[14,19],[5,13],[-1,0],[-7,-4],[-12,7],[-12,10],[-4,2],[-5,1],[-12,-1],[-4,2],[-3,2],[-2,2],[-2,5],[-2,3],[-9,9],[-1,3],[-7,8],[-64,49],[-7,-1],[-6,-2],[-19,-13],[-7,-2],[-5,-1],[-7,0],[-5,3],[-14,10],[-4,5],[-2,4],[-1,6],[-1,3],[-1,3],[-2,1],[-19,15],[-14,18],[0,1],[-19,30],[-1,5],[-1,7],[1,5],[-1,7],[-1,5],[-2,3],[-11,11],[-6,5],[-5,2],[-1,2],[0,2],[4,16],[2,8],[3,3],[2,3],[3,2],[0,1],[0,1],[-10,6],[-4,5],[-1,4],[2,3],[5,2],[17,6],[4,2],[2,4],[2,5],[-2,2],[-3,1],[-3,0],[-4,0],[-4,1],[-5,6],[-1,4],[1,4],[26,33],[4,6],[3,10],[2,3],[2,3],[2,2],[9,4],[3,2],[2,2],[4,7],[2,1],[3,2],[6,2],[22,1],[4,1],[4,4],[0,3],[-2,3],[-3,1],[-16,4],[-3,4],[-2,3],[-2,10],[0,2],[2,6],[3,6],[5,4],[13,8],[4,5],[2,3],[-1,9],[-1,0],[-73,5],[-4,3],[-17,16],[-24,15],[-16,13],[-22,13],[-2,2],[-3,3],[-1,3],[-2,4],[-1,4],[-1,8],[0,3],[0,4],[1,3],[7,11],[5,5],[3,1],[29,11],[17,10],[7,2],[50,3],[4,3],[6,12],[17,13],[5,5],[3,5],[1,3],[-1,4],[-3,3],[-16,17],[-3,0],[-3,0],[-3,-1],[-13,-11],[-18,-8],[-2,-2],[-3,-3],[-3,-6],[-2,-2],[-2,-2],[-4,-2],[-5,-1],[-7,1],[-3,1],[0,3],[4,5],[1,3],[0,4],[-1,3],[-2,3],[-5,7],[-3,7],[0,4],[0,5],[1,4],[2,3],[2,2],[18,9],[6,4],[4,5],[1,4],[1,4],[2,12],[1,5],[2,4],[2,2],[13,6],[3,3],[2,4],[2,9],[-1,11],[1,6],[1,4],[4,8],[3,8],[2,3],[2,3],[3,1],[4,1],[13,1],[4,2],[4,3],[4,7],[1,3],[-1,3],[-11,4],[-4,3],[-3,3],[-6,10],[-1,1],[-4,2],[-15,4],[-19,2],[-3,2],[-3,3],[-5,8],[-1,2],[-3,1],[-20,1],[-11,5],[-7,6],[-8,21],[0,4],[0,5],[1,4],[4,5],[3,2],[9,8],[3,4],[1,4],[-1,3],[-2,4],[-1,5],[-1,7],[1,5],[2,3],[7,2],[4,2],[4,4],[6,10],[3,5],[4,4],[8,5],[3,1],[3,1],[2,1],[33,21],[7,3],[12,1],[8,-2],[3,-1],[10,-12],[3,-2],[3,-1],[5,-1],[5,1],[26,6],[8,0],[8,-2],[3,-1],[34,-31],[4,-1],[6,-2],[5,2],[14,8],[6,3],[9,1],[4,2],[2,3],[1,4],[0,15],[0,3],[-2,3],[-4,9],[-1,7],[-27,14],[-24,3],[-5,2],[-3,2],[-5,10],[-16,16],[-3,5],[-1,5],[0,3],[0,4],[-4,16],[-5,12],[-17,32],[-3,5],[-32,29],[-3,4],[0,1],[-1,3],[1,3],[2,2],[24,13],[2,3],[1,4],[-1,8],[-3,5],[-3,4],[-22,20],[-41,29],[-6,2],[-24,4],[-12,4]],[[6859,3061],[0,16],[-7,10],[-10,15],[-16,28],[-23,26],[-9,14],[-1,14],[7,9],[12,6],[28,3],[13,5],[23,15],[15,0],[15,-16],[38,-85],[12,-13],[16,-12],[18,-7],[20,0],[1,2],[1,4],[2,4],[5,3],[6,-1],[9,-4],[5,-1],[11,1],[9,2],[18,9],[-4,12],[2,8],[5,6],[5,6],[6,-2],[5,0],[6,3],[6,6],[-9,0],[-33,-6],[-7,-4],[-5,-14],[-11,-5],[-7,1],[-21,2],[-28,9],[-25,15],[-20,19],[-16,20],[-75,139],[-3,12],[1,13],[8,14],[43,60],[34,37],[5,4],[6,9],[26,16],[8,9],[-56,1],[-23,9],[-18,21],[-5,31],[8,69],[-8,25],[10,16],[15,8],[60,19],[10,1],[9,-6],[5,-1],[2,4],[2,5],[5,5],[6,4],[5,2],[-8,10],[23,19],[3,15],[-12,-7],[-11,-4],[-20,-2],[-3,3],[-10,19],[-1,8],[4,5],[7,4],[5,5],[13,20],[9,8],[21,7],[7,9],[13,25],[-11,13],[-16,25],[-9,16],[-2,9],[14,4],[14,12],[10,16],[0,18],[-5,0],[-2,-14],[-9,-11],[-20,-13],[-23,-10],[-12,-8],[-5,-10],[-5,-14],[-12,-6],[-29,-2],[-9,6],[-9,13],[-4,15],[6,9],[-4,11],[-6,9],[-7,4],[-9,-4],[3,-12],[-2,-13],[-4,-12],[-2,-10],[-3,-8],[-19,-20],[-11,-19],[-7,-9],[-17,-8],[-2,-11],[2,-12],[0,-11],[-23,27],[-6,5],[-10,0],[-9,2],[-8,4],[-6,7],[2,14],[3,15],[0,14],[-10,7],[0,6],[22,6],[5,26],[-2,31],[2,19],[-11,-5],[-5,-10],[-6,-23],[6,-18],[-10,-4],[-15,1],[-10,-2],[-14,-4],[-14,11],[-23,35],[-19,20],[-9,12],[-3,15],[1,7],[3,7],[1,8],[-4,13],[-2,10],[-2,1],[-15,7],[-22,38],[-15,11],[-61,71],[-11,4],[-3,4],[-7,13],[-6,6],[4,7],[7,6],[3,3],[14,31],[17,72],[22,41],[9,23],[4,8],[6,4],[14,4],[7,4],[8,9],[10,15],[6,18],[-6,15],[21,54],[13,25],[15,15],[13,2],[7,-5],[7,-6],[10,-4],[7,1],[27,12],[-8,5],[-33,13],[17,15],[10,7],[41,10],[8,-2],[4,-4],[4,-3],[5,-4],[24,-6],[13,-1],[54,13],[12,7],[-45,0],[0,6],[12,2],[10,5],[10,3],[13,-4],[0,7],[-16,6],[-3,-1]],[[6881,4636],[3,17],[8,14],[1,4],[1,24],[3,5],[3,1],[4,-1],[25,-10],[4,-1],[11,2],[3,2],[3,3],[10,20],[4,3],[21,8],[4,3],[5,4],[2,4],[14,17],[18,22],[10,6],[11,2],[29,11],[17,10],[14,11],[8,11],[16,20],[11,7],[8,2],[4,4],[2,4],[2,7],[0,3],[0,3],[-1,2],[-2,3],[-1,4],[0,6],[1,4],[3,3],[9,6],[35,35],[57,42],[7,2],[16,3],[9,-1],[4,-2],[6,-4],[2,-2],[4,-1],[6,0],[13,7],[5,4],[3,5],[3,8],[2,5],[5,7],[4,3],[19,7],[7,6],[8,6],[19,3],[7,3],[14,7],[8,8],[6,7],[3,4],[1,4],[0,4],[-1,3],[-2,3],[-2,2],[-14,17],[-2,3],[0,3],[0,3],[0,1],[0,2],[0,2],[-1,3],[-7,11],[-8,11],[-11,16],[-10,23],[-2,6],[-1,4],[-1,3],[-2,2],[-7,7],[-2,2],[-2,3],[0,4],[-1,3],[-3,2],[-10,5],[-3,2],[-1,3],[-1,3],[0,4],[0,5],[3,2],[3,2],[8,2],[25,0],[10,2],[6,2],[5,5],[35,43],[4,5],[2,8],[3,3],[3,3],[6,4],[7,6],[3,2],[11,4],[3,2],[16,13],[3,5],[2,5],[1,14],[3,7],[3,3],[3,2],[30,9]],[[7546,5390],[8,-14],[85,-88],[10,-21],[6,-11],[14,-8],[4,-6],[3,-7],[3,-3],[6,1],[4,5],[3,4],[2,2],[8,-1],[8,-3],[8,-8],[6,-13],[-14,0],[0,-5],[8,-4],[23,5],[14,-1],[44,-26],[0,-6],[-4,-6],[2,-7],[4,-6],[7,-7],[-9,-5],[0,-7],[6,-2],[12,-10],[0,-6],[-5,-8],[3,-5],[6,-3],[5,-4],[3,-11],[2,-61],[-1,-9],[-3,-15],[-1,-5],[0,-8],[4,-19],[16,-24],[2,-16],[-1,-4],[-1,-5],[-2,-3],[-3,-4],[-3,-7],[2,-6],[2,-6],[2,-6],[3,-11],[8,-10],[15,-13],[-5,-12],[3,-6],[6,-5],[5,-9],[-2,-9],[-5,-8],[-3,-8],[3,-9],[11,-14],[3,-7],[2,-19],[6,-20],[3,-6],[2,-1],[8,-3],[3,-2],[1,-2],[2,-8],[11,-23],[5,-8],[4,-8],[3,-12],[4,-10],[7,-5]
```

And this is how my replacement new.json file starts out:

```
{"type":"Topology","objects":{"subunits":{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"Polygon","id":"id1","arcs":[[-1,-2,-3,-4]]},...
```

The numbers in the 'arcs' columns go much much higher in the new.json file (like into the thousands) while the numbers used in the uk.json file generally stay under 100. I think this might have something to do with the scale issues but I'm so new to json that I can't figure out how to solve the problem. I don't know how to pick a projection and data that will best map my data. Any advice? I would be glad to upload the json files but am not sure where I can do that.

Thanks!